# How to delete particular white space inside of string

Tags: c#, .net, string, char

I have string like this

```
<order id="15221" number="5" description="Deposit" currency="USD" amount="100" email="testyan@gmail.com" card_token="true" />
```

I want remove the last white space to get string like this

```
<order id="15221" number="5"  currency="USD" amount="100" email="testyan@gmail.com" card_token="true"/>
```

How can i do this?I am using c#

Comment: `var result = myString.Replace("\" />", "\"/>");` maybe?

Comment: And what have you tried? Why should we give you the solution when you could easily google it yourself? Apart from this: why do you even need this? Generally you shouldn´t modify or read an Xml as string, but instead use some serializer/de-serializer.

Comment: Why do you think that i have not tried?Could you please google it and give me the url of the solution?

Comment: I supposed it because you didn´t post anything that proves what you´ve tried. In particular posting what you´ve tried helps others to post meaningful answers that help you. I doubt you want the exact same solution you´ve already tried yourself.

Comment: Out of curiosity - why? The first string with the whitespace looks better and it's the way more common way to write it.

Comment: I need to get exact string for base64 encoding due to that white space my base64 was wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use

```
s = s.Remove(s.LastIndexOf(" "), 1);
```

Comment: Doesn't really work if the input string is already correct - this will just drop any last white space, with no validation what so ever. Though, maybe that's exactly what OP wants.